# How to optimize image pixel reading in python?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, python-imaging-library

I am trying to create images using masks by matching white pixels in the mask with the original image and copying it.

```
def overlay_images(original_path, mask_path, output_path):
    original = Image.open(original_path)
    mask = Image.open(mask_path)

    # Ensure both images have the same dimensions
    if original.size != mask.size:
        mask = mask.resize(original.size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

    # Create a new image with transparent background
    merged = Image.new('RGBA', original.size, (0, 0, 0, 0))

    # Iterate through each pixel and apply overlay only on white regions of the mask
    for x in range(original.width):
        for y in range(original.height):
            r, g, b, a = mask.getpixel((x, y))
            if r == 255 and g == 255 and b == 255:
                merged.putpixel((x, y), original.getpixel((x, y)))
            
    output_filename = os.path.splitext(output_path)[0] + '.png'
    merged.save(output_filename, "PNG")
```

The for loop iterates through every pixel of both the original and mask images, extracts their pixel values, checks if the pixel in the mask is white, and if it is, copies the pixel value from the original image to the merged image.

How can I optimize this process and maybe do it with less computational power?

Comment: merged = np.where(mask==(255, 255, 255), input, merged)

Comment: Thanks @fmw42, I integrated your code in my function and it works faster than before but still takes up significant time to process. Any way I can speed it up more?

Comment: Sorry, I would not know.  Perhaps some one else might comment.

Comment: Did you remove the for-loops and use just the one `np.where` call? The execution time shouldn't be too long at all, unless your images are very large.

Comment: Yes, I did remove the for loops and using np.where once.

Comment: It's hard to assist when you haven't a) shared your images, or b) said what your timings are or c) said what environment you are running or d) showed your current code showing how you timed it.